# Prove that $\bigcup_{x\in \mathcal O}]x-r,x+r[=\bigcup_{x\in \mathcal O\cap \mathbb Q}]x-r,x+r[$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal O\subset \mathbb R$ an open. Then, for all $x\in \mathcal O$, there is $r>0$ with $r\in \mathbb Q$ s.t. $I_x:=]x-r,x+r[\subset \mathcal O$. Then,
$$\mathcal O=\bigcup_{x\in \mathcal O}I_x.$$
I want to prove that the union can be countable and thus that $$\mathcal O=\bigcup_{x\in \mathcal O\cap \mathbb Q}I_x.$$ 
How can I do it ?

Comment: What is an "ope"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which $r$s you choose, you don't necessarily get $\mathcal O$ back by doing that.

Since your $r$ can depend on $x$, what you really have there is a function $r:\mathcal O\to\mathbb Q^+$ such that $(x+r(x),x-r(x))$.

Now take, for example $\mathcal O=\mathbb R$ (which is certainly an open set) and the following $r$

$$ r(x) = \begin{cases} 42 & \text{if }x=\pi \\
       \dfrac1{\left\lceil \frac{1}{|x-\pi|} \right\rceil} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
This function satisfies your condition, but
$$ \bigcup_{x\in\mathbb Q} (x-r(x),x+r(x)) $$
is $\mathbb R\setminus\{\pi\}$, not $\mathbb R$.

---

However, if you choose $r(x)$ more carefully -- for example specify that $r(x)=1/n$ where $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(x-1/n,x+1/n)\subseteq\mathcal O$ -- then you *can* always get equality.

Answer (score 0):

As phrased, this is false. Let $m=\mu(\mathcal{O})$ be the (Lebesgue) measure of $\mathcal{O}$ if its measure is finite, or $m=1$ otherwise, and enumerate
$$\mathcal{O} \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{ x_n : n \ge 0 \}$$
By choosing $I_{x_n}$ to have width $<\frac{m}{2^{n+2}}$ for all $n \ge 0$, it follows that
$$\mu\left( \bigcup_{x \in \mathcal{O} \cap \mathbb{Q}} I_x \right) = \mu\left( \bigcup_{n \ge 0} I_{x_n} \right) \le \sum_{n \ge 0} \mu(I_{x_n}) < \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{m}{2^{n+2}} = \frac{m}{2} < m$$
so it is impossible that $\bigcup_{x \in \mathcal{O} \cap \mathbb{Q}} I_x = \mathcal{O}$.